# element.setcapture() is deprecated Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deprecated

I am making a Vue.js project with the google books API.

Everything was fine until this error came out of nowhere :

> element.setcapture() is deprecated. use element.setpointercapture()
> instead For more informations :
> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture

I don't use a setcapture() explicitely but maybe it is related to

```
<div v-if="imageLinks" class="BookCard" 
@mouseover="isMobile ? null : vueInfo = true"
@click="isMobile ? vueInfo = !vueInfo : null" 
@mouseleave="isMobile ? null : vueInfo = false">
```

Even when I re-use the precedent repo, the same occurs. Until 3 days ago I didn't have any error.

The problem is that hover in css and in the code above didn't work an

Put this be related to a software update ?

If you want to check the full code, this is my git :
https://github.com/LaurianeGelebart/web_project.git

Thank you

Comment: Browser api deprecation notices can be ignored most times, especially if you're not directly responsible for using them.

Answer (score 0):

I restored the z index to 0 and that solved it!